# Array (String?) Parameter in SOAP Call

Tags: php, node.js, soap, soap-client

I'm trying to call a SOAP method to a service I haven't control over, a method that looks like this:

```
    <Body>
        <AddUserByWEB xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <token>[string?]</token>
            <email>[string?]</email>
            <password>[string?]</password>
            <userType>[string?]</userType>
            <userRole>[string?]</userRole>
            <dateStart>[string?]</dateStart>
            <dateEnd>[string?]</dateEnd>
            <userName>[string?]</userName>
            <personName>[string?]</personName>
            <personSurname>[string?]</personSurname>
            <phoneNumber>[string?]</phoneNumber>
            <!-- Optional -->
            <resourcesID>
                <string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">[string?]</string>
            </resourcesID>
            <!-- Optional -->
            <resourcesPermisions>
                <string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">[string?]</string>
            </resourcesPermisions>
        </AddUserByWEB>
    </Body>
```

I'd like to know how can I pass data to the resourcesID array (string?) in a server side language such as PHP or node.js.

It seems that those two parameters are waiting for ArrayOfstring data:

```
resourcesID: 'q28:ArrayOfstring',
resourcesPermisions: 'q29:ArrayOfstring'
```

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on WSDL definition.

Comment: @michail_w could you please give me some examples? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find out, by pure chance, how to solve this. The resourcesID parameters actually expects a list of arrays with the key resourceID:

```
var args = {
    token: 'h38hsa0-123',
    email: 'email@example.com',
    password: 'test',
    userType: 1,
    userRole: 'User',
    dateStart: '27-01-2016 00:00:00',
    dateEnd: '27-01-2016 00:00:00',
    userName: 'ss',
    personName: 'ss',
    personSurname: 'ss',
    phoneNumber: '231',
    resourcesID: [
        {string: 1}
    ],
    resourcesPermisions: [
        {string: 'Write'}
    ]
};
```